# content to display by month in archive always shows current month rather then the month selected?

Tags: category-archive

on this http://ee2.acer.edu.au/rd/archive/2013/April

I have this code

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="research-developments" status="Featured|Open" orderby="entry_date" sort="desc"  dynamic="off" display_by="month" limit="1"}
```

but it always shows latest month so at the moment I have may for all archives when I need it to display each for each section , any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

If dynamic is "off", the channel:entries isn't influenced by URL parameters.

Comment: Also you might want to look at the documentation and parameter values. In EE 2.6 orderby does not take "entry_date". 

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#orderby

and going on what Robson said, you might should put a start date using the url segments to get the correct month